# Вывод кириллицы в XML

Tags: php, xml, кодировка

Здравствуйте!

Имеется следующий код для обработки xml:

```
<?php 
$vitrina =  simplexml_load_file('URL');
foreach ($vitrina->section->tour as $tour) {
echo "<h2>". $tour->resort. "</h2>";
echo "<p>Отель: ". $tour->hotel. "</p>";
echo "<p>Вылет: ". $tour->departure. "</p>";
echo "<p><a href=". $tour->bookurl. ">Забронировать</a></p>";
} 
?>
```

При отображении результата на сайте - ошибка кодировки, кириллица выводится кракозябрами...  Пробовал указывать кодировку в теге meta - безрезультатно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это правильно.

Comment: PHP-исходники в Windows-1251,
В коде XML, отдающемуся по URL, кодировка не указана,
В заголовке Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
В мете charset=windows-1251
Кириллица отображается так: РђРЅС‚Р°Р»СЊСЏ

Comment: Значит, XML в UTF-8 (как и должно быть).

Answer (score 1):

Понятно что ничего не понятно. В какой кодировке PHP-исходники, в какой XML, какие HTTP-заголовки отдаются, есть ли AddDefaultCharset в .htaccess, что в мете, что на скриншоте в браузере?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поменять кодировку в контент-тип

```
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=window-1251");
```